# How do I split a dataframe with the condition of value in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe and one of the column named beat includes binary values. Here, I want to split the dataframe so that every time `beat==1` a new dataframe is formed.

Example of current dataframe:

```
frame    value    beat
1        4        0
2        5        0
3        3        0
4        6        1
5        7        0
6        4        0
7        2        1
8        3        0
9        3        0
10       1        0
11       4        0
12       8        0
13       7        1
14       9        0
15       2        0
```

Desired dataframes:

```
frame    value    beat
4        6        1
5        7        0
6        4        0

frame    value    beat
7        2        1
8        3        0
9        3        0
10       1        0
11       4        0
12       8        0

frame    value    beat
13       7        1
14       9        0
15       2        0
```

I've tried using split according to nrow but since each number of rows are different I'll have to do it manually. I'm still very new to R so I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When with `base R`, you can use `split()` along with `findInterval()` to make it:

```
lst <- split(df,findInterval(seq(nrow(df)), which(df$beat==1)))
```

and `lst[names(lst)!="0"]` yields the desired output:

```
> lst[names(lst)!="0"]
$`1`
  frame value beat
4     4     6    1
5     5     7    0
6     6     4    0

$`2`
   frame value beat
7      7     2    1
8      8     3    0
9      9     3    0
10    10     1    0
11    11     4    0
12    12     8    0

$`3`
   frame value beat
13    13     7    1
14    14     9    0
15    15     2    0
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use `split` with `cumsum` to create groups when `beat = 1`

```
split(df, cumsum(df$beat == 1))
```

Looking at the desired output it seems you want to ignore the rows until first 1, in that case first subset the dataframe and then `split`

```
temp <- df[which.max(df$beat) : nrow(df), ]
split(temp, cumsum(temp$beat == 1))

#$`1`
#  frame value beat
#4     4     6    1
#5     5     7    0
#6     6     4    0

#$`2`
#   frame value beat
#7      7     2    1
#8      8     3    0
#9      9     3    0
#10    10     1    0
#11    11     4    0
#12    12     8    0

#$`3`
#   frame value beat
#13    13     7    1
#14    14     9    0
#15    15     2    0
```

Comment: I've tried the code you suggested but only the first dataframe from my output was correct. The rest of the dataframes did not start from 1. It might have been of my lack of knowledge of `cumsum`. Mind if you explain it a little?

Comment: @ngxs_24 Do you have numbers other than 0 and 1 in `beat` ? Can you check if `split(temp, cumsum(temp$beat == 1))[-1]` works ?

Comment: Oh, it seems to work fine now when I tried it again. I'm not sure what went wrong but it probably was a mistake in my code. Sorry for the trouble and thank you for the help! Just a quick question, what does the [-1] at the end mean?

Comment: @ngxs_24 it actually removes the first element from the list. See for example, `x <- 1:10`, and then try `x[-1]` it removes 1 from the list.